# libgdal.so android error: could not load library "libgdal.so.1"

Tags: android, qt, gdal

My problem is the following: I have succesfully built `GDAL 1.10.1` using an Android toolchain `(CC=i686-linux-android-gcc, CXX=i686-linux-android-c++)` that produces the following output libraries `libgdal.a`, `libgdal.la`, `libgdal.lai`, `libgdal.so`, `libgdal.so.1`, `libgdal.so.1.17.1` in the output folder `.libs` (in the following I'll call this folder `$GDAL_LIB_PATH`).

I am trying to build a simple Android app (a simple widget application with a `QPushButton` named `TestAndroid`) using Qt 5.4 on Windows. If I don't use GDAL everything works fine and I am able to run my app on an Android emulator for all available platforms: `x86`, `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7`.

Nonetheless, if I try to use `GDAL` (ex. by simply calling `GDALAllRegister()` in the initialization of the app) and then linking to `libgdal.so` the application crashes with the following error:

> E/art     ( 1614):
>   dlopen("/data/app/org.qtproject.example.TestAndroid-1/lib/x86/libTestAndroid.so",
>   RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: could not load library
>   "libgdal.so.1" needed by "libTestAndroid.so"; caused by library
>   "libgdal.so.1" not found

I have verified that the Android platform is the right one (x86), otherwise the linker would skip the wrong `libgdal.so` object.

I have included `libgdal.so` in the `*.apk` (generated by Qt) using `ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS *= $GDAL_LIB_PATH/libgdal.so`. The other files `libgdal.so.x.x` cannot be included in the same way since Qt prevents it.

In order to avoid dynamic linking I have also tried to link my app with `libgdal.a` but many link-time errors appears (ex. undefined reference to 'atof')

I have searched on the web but I have not found a solution to my problem.

I am not constrained to use dynamic linking so, a solution to any of the following problems is good for me:

1. Is there a way to avoid the creation of `libgdal.so.x.x` files when building GDAL ?
2. Is there a way to include `libgdal.so.x.x` files in the `*.apk` file generated by Qt ?
3. How can I avoid link-time errors when linking the static library `libgdal.a` ?

Thanks in advance for any reply!

Comment: Hi, same problem here. Kindly update me when you resolve yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126189/building-android-app-on-qt-using-additional-library-assimp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several days of trials and errors (mainly errors) I have found a solution to my problem.

I'm writing it as an answer to my question so that it may be helpful to others.

The problem was during the link-time of `GDAL`. Briefly: the linker created the "real name" shared library `libgdal.so.1.17.1` together with the links to it `libgdal.so.1` and `libgdal.so`.

For some reasons (which I ignore) forcing the link to `libgdal.so`, the linker searches for `libgdal.so.1` (which, in turn, would have searched for `libgdal.so.1.17.1`).

The workaround that solved my problem can be summarized in the following steps:

1. In the `GDAL` root, run the `./configure` according to the desired configuration (see http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid) checking that libtool is `ENABLED`
2. Edit the created libtool file (e. g. with `gedit`) as follows:

   - replace the value of **library_names_spec** with **library_names_spec="\$libname\${shared_ext}"**
   - replace the value of **soname_spec** with **soname_spec=""**
3. Type make

In the output folder `.libs/` the only `libgdal.so` will be created and now the link to `libgdal.so` seems to work fine.